# local notification handling

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to crack the way local notification work.

I wrote this line in order to present the notification I scheduled:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

}
```

The issue is that it runs endless number of times.

If I write something else it runs only one time, but i understood that this line should pop up the message of the notification.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`presentLocalNotificationNow` is triggering `didReceiveLocalNotification` which in turn is calling `presentLocalNotificationNow`... so you end up with an endless loop.

Comment: Well, i guess i could of thought about that my self :) You have a solution to this?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the app receives the notification?  I'm not sure I understand your goals.

Comment: I want two things to happen:

Comment: 1. pop up a notification message

Comment: 2. activate a method on a different class

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

I didn't realize that by reaching the didReceiveLocation method it automatically sends a notification message if the iPhone is not activated.

No need to write anything...